# Need to make a dynamic FIFO queue of a lists of items

Tags: c#, queue

I want to create a FIFO queue of all items which are there in my list.  I need to retrieve the items of the list from the queue.

This is my code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CHPCanControl
{
  public class signals
 {
    public double quant;
    public int Ind;
    public int Subin;
    public int Control;
    public int dat;
    public List<signals> signalList;

    public signals(double quant, int Ind, int Subin, int Control, int dat)
    {

        this.quant = quant;
        this.Ind = Ind;
        this.Control = Control;
        this.Subin = Subin;
        this.dat = dat;
    }
 }

 public class Controlsignal 
{
   public List<signals> signalList = new List<signals>(); // this is my first list

    public void main()
    {
        signalList.Add(new signals(1, 1000, 1, 0x60, 1));
        signalList.Add(new signals(1, 1000, 2, 0x60, 1));
        signalList.Add(new signals(1, 1000, 3, 0x60, 1));
        signalList.Add(new signals(1, 1000, 4, 0x60, 1));
        signalList.Add(new signals(0.5, 1000, 5, 0x60, 200));
        signalList.Add(new signals(1, 1000, 6, 0x60, 1));
        signalList.Add(new signals(1, 1000, 7, 0x60, 1));
        signalList.Add(new signals(0.0625, 1000, 8, 0x60, 1));
        signalList.Add(new signals(0.1, 1000, 9, 0x60, 1));
        signalList.Add(new signals(0.1, 1000, 10, 0x60, 1));
    }
  }

   public class Statussignal
{
   public List<signals> signalList1 = new List<signals>(); // this is my second list

    public void main()
    {
        signalList1.Add(new signals(1, 1100, 1, 0x40, 1));
        signalList1.Add(new signals(1, 1100, 2, 0x40, 1));
        signalList1.Add(new signals(1, 1100, 3, 0x40, 1));
        signalList1.Add(new signals(0.0002, 1100, 4, 0x40, 1));
        signalList1.Add(new signals(0.5, 1100, 5, 0x40, 200));
        signalList1.Add(new signals(1, 1100, 6, 0x40, 1));
        signalList1.Add(new signals(1, 1100, 7, 0x40, 1));
        signalList1.Add(new signals(1, 1100, 8, 0x40, 1));
    }
  }
 }
```

My problem is that I want to add the items of my both the lists in a FIFO queue.  I am thinking that I may need to access the queue from multiple threads.

Thank you very  much guys for the reply I am trying to do with this way but I am not sure is it correct or not..

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.ComponentModel;
  using System.Data;
  using System.Drawing;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.IO;
  using System.Windows.Forms;
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
  using System.Threading;


 namespace CHPCanControl
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    Controlsignal control = new Controlsignal();
    Statussignal status = new Statussignal();
    Calibrationparameters calibration = new Calibrationparameters();


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // need to do something here by which you will receieve 
        // your messages here from the ECU

        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.ECU_Send));
        thread.Start();
        thread.IsBackground = true;

    }
    public void ECU_Send()
    {
        private Queue<control.signalList> queue = new Queue<control.signalList>();
        public event EventHandler Changed;
        protected virtual void OnChanged()
        {
            if(Changed != null)
            {
                Changed(this,EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    public int Count { get { return queue.Count; } }

    public virtual void Enqueue(control.signalList item)
    {
        queue.Enqueue(item);
            OnChanged();
    }


    public virtual void Dequeue()
    {
       control.signalList item = queue.Dequeue();
        OnChanged();
        return item;
    }
   }
  }
```

Comment: Use a `Queue<signal>` instead of a list.

Comment: If you want it to be more thread safe you can use `ConcurrentQueue` or `BlockingCollection`.

Comment: Thank you very much guys for the reply I additionally added my code above please look at this

Answer (score 2):

- For FIFO you should use a `Queue<T>`.
- For LIFO you should use a `Stack<T>`.

More information about collections etc can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379571%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

If you are using **.NET 4 or above** you could use `ConcurrentQueue<T>`, read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx).
If you are using **.NET 3.5 or below** you can use **Synchronize** the queue for thread safety and a great example can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.synchronized.aspx).

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
public class SamplesQueue  {

   public static void Main()  {

      // Creates and initializes a new Queue.
      Queue myQ = new Queue();
      myQ.Enqueue( "The" );
      myQ.Enqueue( "quick" );
      myQ.Enqueue( "brown" );
      myQ.Enqueue( "fox" );

      // Creates a synchronized wrapper around the Queue.
      Queue mySyncdQ = Queue.Synchronized( myQ );

      // Displays the sychronization status of both Queues.
      Console.WriteLine( "myQ is {0}.", myQ.IsSynchronized ? "synchronized" : "not synchronized" );
      Console.WriteLine( "mySyncdQ is {0}.", mySyncdQ.IsSynchronized ? "synchronized" : "not synchronized" );
   }
}
/* 
This code produces the following output.

myQ is not synchronized.
mySyncdQ is synchronized.
*/
```

Comment: This should really be a comment, unless you plan to elaborate.

Comment: A `Stack` is not a Queue.  A `Queue` is a Queue.  Stacks also aren't particularly "more common" than queues.  There's no indication, given what he's asked for, to think he needs a stack.

Comment: Thank you very  much guys for the reply I am trying to do with this way but I am not sure is it correct or not..

Comment: @user1465977 Then update the code in the question with your attempts at using a `Queue`.

Comment: Expanded my answer to include different angles depending on the version of .NET you are using.

Answer (score 0):

It almost sounds like you just want to use `IEnumerable`.  It's a ways of reading all of the items from the list through a read-only interface.  You can use `Concat` in LINQ to get an `IEnumerable` that represents the items from both lists.

However, `IEnumerable` is not thread safe, so if you plan to access the queue from multiple threads then you'll want to use a `BlockingCollection`, which will wrap a `ConcurrentQueue` by default.  Then you can just add all of the items from both lists to the queue and read it from any number of threads.